# Facebook AppRequests not showing on Windows App

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-graph-api, uwp, windows-store-apps

We are using Facebook Windows SDK https://microsoft.github.io/winsdkfb/ in Unity3D UWP platform, because regular Facebook Unity SDK does not support this platform. Everything seems to be working great, apart from AppRequests, they do not appear to friends(test or real accounts registered as testers) in Facebook Windows Store (desktop) client.

We added Windows App platform in Basic Settings in Facebook App dashboard and filled the information Windows 10 App Store URL and Windows Store SID. In the game build we can login to Facebook and get friends, but when sending app-requests they do not appear in Facebook app from Windows Store. We also tested it by adding another platform to Facebook App dashboard (Facebook Web Games), with this platform existing in the basic settings, we managed to test app-requests sent from the same Unity UWP game build for Windows Store. They do appear to test accounts but only in Facebook web-browser version. This leaves us with thoughts that the Facebook Windows SDK from Microsoft(winsdkfb) does work, and the issue is most likely on Facebook side. But it is still unclear if it is related to Facebook back-end or to desktop version from Windows Store.

I would expect everything to be working anyway with test accounts, in case if we are missing user_friends permission.

Maybe we are missing with some configurations or validations on Facebook App dashboard.